Are there any email discussion lists popular in cognitive science or psychology?
In the world of the programming language, R, there is the R tag on stack overflow and there is the old-school r-help mailing list. From an infrastructure perspective Stack Overflow is so much better, but r-help has a really smart community.

Are there any popular email discussion lists in psychology or cognitive science?


There seems to be a whole host of APA student listservs.  I don't know how active any of them are, and they may be laden with spam and junk.
